# Using Android license verification serverside

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I've been thinking about implementing of Google Play licence check on my Java server. Is that even possible? I haven't been able to find anything on this matter. I know Android LVL is written in Java, but I'm not sure if it can run outside of dalvik machine. Is there a posibillty of checking Google account name or some kind of device ID against Google Play to check whether an app has been bought in a Java server application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it's possible, the java sources are out there and could be downloaded (and afaik, the jar is not dexed until you compile your application) - see some kind of manual over there at [developers.android.com](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) to read about how to get the sources
2. I've heard about [a PHP project](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/) trying to attempt it, but using java should be no problem at all - you do the same things on the server, the [manuals state for the client](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) - and let the client sends the encrypted response from the market directly to the server via SSL (e.g. byte[] post)
3. You should get a UID from [ResponseData.userId](https://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/ResponseData.java?r=9cd599d6902d8b9b8311e4ef8dd20dcccb5e7aba)

Read some more in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html) and [more info and links in another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800590/2188682)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is simply verifying response data (returned by google LVL on android device) on app server.

I think the question is asking if it's possible to call some google web API to do Google Play license check on its app server. But it seems like google doesn't open the web API interface to its licensing server, all LVL calls need to be done using its google play service framework on android device.