# Google Play Licensing Server Sided check

Tags: android, google-play, licensing

> How does one verify that the [paid] app is licensed and was bought
>   through google play?

as a guy that usually de-compiles and modifies android applications as a hobby I'm really concerned about releasing my paid app into the google play market without some kind of protection.

I was thinking of hosting the core of the app in a server and having it attach a license key or google play's response when making the request so I can check it against Google and verify the app is actually licensed.

This question is asking the same thing: 
[Using Android license verification serverside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422922/using-android-license-verification-serverside)

But it doesn't cover how do I forward the response from google play to my server and how to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like google doesn't open the web API interface to its licensing server, all LVL calls need to be done using its google play service framework on android device.

The recommendation from google to is simply verifying response data (returned by google LVL on android device) on app server, which is not secure enough.